# Use cell value as worksheet name for reference in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

since I named my worksheets in Google Sheets in a specific way, I would like to use the cell value in my master worksheet as a reference. I have tried things like =SUM(INDIRECT("A3")&!H2:H500) but couldn't make it work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with quotes and parentheses:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'"&A3&"'!H2:H500"))
```